# Grouping by ID column and collapsing Boolean columns for summary

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Trying to transform a dataframe with multiple boolean columns for rows with duplicate IDs into a new dataframe where there is only one entry for each ID but the boolean values are combined for the ID groups. I also want to carry down the latest date value.

Example input:

```
     ID S1 S2 S3 S4  Date
1   ex1  1  0  0  0  4/7/12
2   ex1  0  1  0  0  6/8/16
3   ex2  0  0  1  0  5/5/15
4   ex3  1  1  0  0  4/19/13
5   ex3  0  1  0  1  6/7/15
6   ex4  0  1  0  0  8/7/09
7   ex5  1  1  1  0  6/12/17
```

Desired output:

```
    ID S1 S2 S3 S4  Date
   ex1  1  1  0  0  6/8/16
   ex2  0  0  1  0  5/5/15
   ex3  1  1  0  1  6/7/15
   ex4  0  1  0  0  8/7/09
   ex5  1  1  1  0  6/12/17
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple summarization as below -

```
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize( S1=max(S1), S2 =max(S2), S3 =max(S3), S4 = max(S4), Date = max(Date) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, lapply(.SD, max), ID]

#     ID S1 S2 S3 S4       Date
# 1: ex1  1  1  0  0 2016-06-08
# 2: ex2  0  0  1  0 2015-05-05
# 3: ex3  1  1  0  1 2015-06-07
# 4: ex4  0  1  0  0 2009-08-07
# 5: ex5  1  1  1  0 2017-06-12
```

This also works:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise_all(max)
```

Or in Base R:

```
do.call(rbind
        , lapply(split(df, df$ID)
                 , function(g) data.frame(lapply(g, max))))
```

Data used:

```
df <- fread("
a     ID S1 S2 S3 S4  Date
1   ex1  1  0  0  0  4/7/12
2   ex1  0  1  0  0  6/8/16
3   ex2  0  0  1  0  5/5/15
4   ex3  1  1  0  0  4/19/13
5   ex3  0  1  0  1  6/7/15
6   ex4  0  1  0  0  8/7/09
7   ex5  1  1  1  0  6/12/17
")[, -1]
df[, Date := lubridate::mdy(Date)]
```